# php mysql pagination for mysql view

Tags: php

i am try to perform pagination from mysql view created but i can only get the first rows when clicked next page nothing displayed. Any help please here is my simple code.

```
 $query=mysql_query("
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW matokeo_mtihani AS SELECT st_id,fname,stream,mname,lname,photo,nidhamu,mahudhurio,ushirikiano,mazingira,exams.mt AS mt_term,mazoezi_mtihani.mt AS mt_maz,exams.bios AS bios_term,mazoezi_mtihani.bios AS bios_maz,exams.ch AS ch_term,mazoezi_mtihani.ch AS ch_maz,exams.ph AS ph_term,mazoezi_mtihani.ph AS ph_maz,exams.civ AS civ_term,mazoezi_mtihani.civ AS civ_maz,exams.geo AS geo_term,mazoezi_mtihani.geo AS geo_maz,exams.hist AS hist_term,mazoezi_mtihani.hist AS hist_maz,exams.kisw AS kisw_term,mazoezi_mtihani.kisw AS kisw_maz,exams.eng AS eng_term,mazoezi_mtihani.eng AS eng_maz,round((exams.eng * $percent_mtihani+mazoezi_mtihani.eng*$percent_mazoezi),1) AS eng_av,round((exams.geo * $percent_mtihani + mazoezi_mtihani.geo *$percent_mazoezi),1) AS geo_av,round((exams.ph * $percent_mtihani+mazoezi_mtihani.ph*$percent_mazoezi),1) AS ph_av,round((exams.ch * $percent_mtihani+mazoezi_mtihani.ch *$percent_mazoezi),1) AS ch_av,round((exams.civ * $percent_mtihani+mazoezi_mtihani.civ *$percent_mazoezi),1) AS civ_av,round((exams.mt * $percent_mtihani+mazoezi_mtihani.mt *$percent_mazoezi),1) AS mt_av,round((exams.kisw * $percent_mtihani+mazoezi_mtihani.kisw *$percent_mazoezi),1) AS kisw_av,round((exams.hist * $percent_mtihani+mazoezi_mtihani.hist *$percent_mazoezi),1) AS hist_av,round((exams.bios * $percent_mtihani+mazoezi_mtihani.bios *$percent_mazoezi),1) AS bios_av,idadi 
,
round(

 (((exams.eng * $percent_mtihani+mazoezi_mtihani.eng*$percent_mazoezi) + (exams.geo * $percent_mtihani+ mazoezi_mtihani.geo *$percent_mazoezi) +(exams.ph * $percent_mtihani+mazoezi_mtihani.ph *$percent_mazoezi)+(exams.ch * $percent_mtihani+mazoezi_mtihani.ch *$percent_mazoezi)+(exams.civ * $percent_mtihani+mazoezi_mtihani.civ *$percent_mazoezi)+(exams.mt * $percent_mtihani+mazoezi_mtihani.mt *$percent_mazoezi)+(exams.kisw * $percent_mtihani+mazoezi_mtihani.kisw *$percent_mazoezi)+(exams.hist * $percent_mtihani+mazoezi_mtihani.hist *$percent_mazoezi)+(exams.bios * $percent_mtihani+mazoezi_mtihani.bios *$percent_mazoezi))) /idadi,1) AS metric_total

FROM mazoezi_mtihani,masomo_idadi ,info,exams,stream,student_characters WHERE (stream .student_reg= mazoezi_mtihani.student_id AND student_characters .regNo= mazoezi_mtihani.student_id AND exams.student_id = mazoezi_mtihani.student_id AND masomo_idadi.student_id = mazoezi_mtihani.student_id AND mazoezi_mtihani.student_id = info.st_id AND form_id='{$_REQUEST['class']}' AND exams.term='{$_REQUEST['month']}' AND exams.academic_year='{$_REQUEST['academic_year']} ' )  
  ORDER BY metric_total DESC")or die("".mysql_error());



//$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM matokeo_mtihani  ");

$sql="SELECT * FROM matokeo_mtihani ";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$total_records = mysql_num_rows($result);

$pages = ceil($total_records / $rows_per_page);




$per_page =30;//define how many games for a page

if(isset($_GET['screen'])){
if($_GET['screen']==""){
$page="1";
}else{
$page=$_GET['screen'];
}
}
else{
$page="1";

}
$start    = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
$sql     = $sql." LIMIT $start,$per_page";
$query_view=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: What is your query string when you click your "next page" link?  What is the URL?

Comment: <a href=client.php?page=print_term_results&class=".$class."&academic_year=".$year."&month=".$term."&screen=" . $s. ">Next</a> @ user1477388

Comment: I would actually like to see what the variables evaluate to.  Can you post what you get in your browser address bar?

Comment: i can only get the first 30 records and when clicked next page no more records displayed though i have 104 records from my view

Comment: I get this url with no records, http://localhost/osais/client.php?page=print_term_results&class=1&academic_year=2013&month=2&screen=2

Comment: Look at your query string:  `?page=print_term_results`  How is your script supposed to perform math on that?  `$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;`  Also, output `$sql` by doing `var_dump($sql);` before you call `$query_view=mysql_query($sql);` to see what you're actually calling.

Comment: I see, you are actually setting `page` to `screen`.  Either way, just output your full SQL query before execution to see what it is.  Then you will know what you will have to change.

Comment: i tried and igot this  string(42) "SELECT * FROM matokeo_mtihani LIMIT 30,30"  i dont think if this has problem coz the view is real exist

Comment: Your SQL looks good; but make sure you can run that in phpMyAdmin and make sure you get results.  Likely, your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: its very wonderfully, in phpmyadmin works fine with all pagination but in that script it doesnt.

Comment: I would have to see the part of your code that uses the `$query_view` recordset.